# Peer management library/package for React Native WebRTC integration?

Tags: react-native, webrtc, peerjs, simple-peer, react-native-webrtc

I'm currently developing a project in **React Native** that heavily relies on WebRTC functionality for peer-to-peer communication. In the web environment, I've found packages like **simple-peer** and **peer.js** immensely helpful in simplifying peer connection management.

I've tried integrating both **react-native-simple-peer** and **react-native-peerjs** for peer management, but unfortunately, neither seems to work seamlessly with **react-native-webrtc**. Has anyone come across a similar situation and found a suitable alternative library or package for **managing peers** in React Native WebRTC applications?

If there is an alternative library available, could you please provide some guidance on how to integrate it with **react-native-webrtc** effectively? Any tips or code snippets would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!